# How do I configure the output-path of ember-cli as a setting?

Tags: ember-cli

I'm using ember as part of a bigger project and so both dev and production build into a subdirectory somewhere else. Can I specify `output-path` as a setting rather than on the commnad line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your `package.json` and add in the scripts there such as:

```
"scripts": {
  "buildprod": "ember build --environment=production --output-path=yourProdPath",
  "builddev": "ember build --output-path=yourDevPath"
}
```

And just run them in the cli `npm buildprod`.

Comment: [it's something](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/adventuretimewithfinnandjake/images/4/49/It's_something_(edited).png/revision/latest?cb=20130221021013)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named **.ember-cli** inside the app folder and mention the output path. Ember will recognize the path automatically when we do "ember build"

```
{
    "outputPath" : "D:/MyApplication/working/ember"
}
```